# Does schedule E income such as Airbnb disqualify unemployment benefits?

Tags: united-states, unemployment, schedule-e

I am a Bay Area California resident who lost my job due to the pandemic orders, and I also haven't been able to run my airbnb listing for the same reason.

I have been receiving unemployment benefits through the PUA program during this time. We are still under strict orders in my area, but if it gets to the point that I can run my airbnb listing again before I get a new job, is that money going to disqualify me from my benefits? I plan on filing this income as Schedule E since it's a passive rental (it's in my home, but I don't provide any guest services), so I'm not sure if that counts as "work" or not.

Just trying to figure out how to plan for all this stuff as best I can!